Check is script is running as Computer Account or as User
I have some scripts been executed at system starts before user logon.
They are executed from Computer Account (PC name).
My bad luck here is because Windows Computer Accounts ends with Dollar Sign "$" and part of bellow script is checking is this script was executed from Computer Account, and if so do some extra actions. Unfortunately its don't work.
If ($env:UserName -contains "$") {
    Write-Host "App run from Computer account: $env:UserName. No need to explorer run."
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "Set Reboot Active"
        $Global:RebootActive = $True
} Else {
    Write-Host "App run from User Account: $env:UserName. Explorer will be started..."
        Start-Process Explorer
}

In line: "If ($env:UserName -contains "$")"
I already tried to replace contains to match, but then script always detect $ even on normal accounts (without dollar sign):

Do anyone know how to fix it or maybe there is another possibly to check is script was run from Computer Account?

Perhaps this can help

-match '\$$' or -like '*$'

-match is a regex operator, and $ has a special meaning in regex - it describes the end of a string.
So, to match a literal $ at the end of a string, you need:
$UserName -match '\$$'

The \ acts as an escape character, so \$ will match the literal $, and $ then ensures it occurs as the last character in the string.
Alternatively, use the -like wildcard operator:
$UserName -match '*$'

